# "1º Noun + 2º Noun " or "2º Noun + of the + 1º Noun"?

Tags: prepositions, nouns

I know this must be a simple question, but I really can't find (probably I don't know how express this question to search in google) the explanation for this.

In the phrase:
    **Full Coverage of the Industry**

Could we say:
    **Industry Full Coverage**

Is there a correct way or any rules that can help us this and in other similar cases?? Usually I use what sounds right for me, but I'm never sure of what is the correct one

---

Same thing for 
**Car Manufacters of Passenger vehicles** or **Passenger vehicles car manufacters**

Thank you all

Comment: Full Industry Coverage would be ok. In such a case, all of the nouns other than the first one are being used as adjectives. Here's a list showing the order in which a string of adjectives normally appears. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order

Comment: @remarkl Is there any rule to cases where is not an adjective: in the following phrase "Analysis of automatic processes", Automatic Processes is not being used as an adjective, but it seems fine for be to say "Automatic Processes Analysis"....

Comment: @MatheusOiveira -  For purpose of analyzing syntax, a word is what the word does.  If you can put it before a noun to modify that noun, it is being used as an adjective. Thus, the list of rules I supplied would apply to your examples. In "Full industry coverage," size (full) precedes type (industry). "Automatic processes" is different because "Automatic Processes" is a thing, in effect, a single adjective rather than a string of independent adjectives.  The point is that whatever word is used *as* an adjective can be fit into the list and should be ordered accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

"Full Industry Coverage" would be ok. In such a case, all of the nouns other than the first one are being used as adjectives. A list showing the order in which a string of adjectives normally appear can be found [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order).